# Split a column into multiple columns that has value as list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem about splitting column into multiple columns
I have a data like table on the top.
column B contains the values of list .
I want to split the values of column B into columns like the right table. The values in the top table will be the number of occurrences of the values in column B (bottom table).

input:

```
A          B
a     [1, 2]
b  [3, 4, 5]
c     [1, 5]
```

expected output:

```
A  1  2  3  4  5
a  1  1  0  0  0
b  0  0  1  1  1
c  1  0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` the column of lists and use `crosstab`:

```
df2 = df.explode('B')
out = pd.crosstab(df2['A'], df2['B']).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
```

output:

```
   A  1  2  3  4  5
0  a  1  1  0  0  0
1  b  0  0  1  1  1
2  c  1  0  0  0  1
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abc'), 'B': [[1,2], [3,4,5], [1,5]]})
```